# How will weight loss effect jump distance

Tags: everyday-life, projectile

I want to see how weight loss would affect my vertical jump.
I weigh 280 pounds and have an 18 in. Vertical. I calculated my initial velocity to be 3 m/s and .306s to reach the top of my jump. Assuming power stays the same and ignoring air resistance, ect about how high could I jump if I lost 30 pounds and weighed 250?

Comment: Power is energy per unit time, meaning that if the power is the same and the time you push the ground is the same, the energy is the same. Since potential energy is $mgh$ and you changed $m$, you can see how much $h$ changes by conserving their product

Comment: Notably, continuing from @OfekGillon, if your initial velocity stayed the same then your jump height wouldn't change. Assuming all of the power gets converted into your initial energy $(mv^2)/2$, you can figure out how much changing $m$ will change your initial velocity. This will also let you calculate how much time it should take to reach the top with the new mass, directly from the (arguably) most fun kinematic equation $v^2-v_{\mathrm{initial}}^2=2 a d$, where $v=0$ at the top of the parabola, $a=-9.81m/s^2$ is the constant acceleration, and $d$ is the distance travelled (vertically)

Comment: If this is your motivator for weight loss, I'm afraid you are going to be disappointed. Just feeling better is probably more tangible.